# eclipse-cdt Problems

Tags: 14.04, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have got a weird problem. I installed eclipse for c/c++ Development using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++
```

after i opened eclipse, i tried to make a new project, but i didn't get an option to choose between types of projects (c project/ c++ project/ Java project) but just the option "project". this project did not generate a src folder. i didn't see an option to create a src folder as well. how do i fix that?

i tried installing it manually with the download from their site, but the program didn't even launch.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for the packages that you installed in Ubuntu 14.04 by running: `sudo apt install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++`

1. Open Eclipse and select *Help* -> *Welcome*.
2. The Welcome screen will appear. In the Welcome screen click *Tutorials*.
3. The Tutorials screen will appear. In the Tutorials screen click *C/C++ Development*.
4. A **Help - Eclipse Platform** window will open. Click *Create a simple application*.
5. The Help - Eclipse Platform window will jump to the *Tutorial: Creating a simple application* section. In this tutorial, you will use the CDT to create a simple 'Hello World' application. The tutorial has screenshots to make it easy to follow.

After you have finished following the Creating a simple application tutorial, don't delete the 'Hello World' project that you made so you can use it as reference material for making your next C++ project.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I was able to get eclipse-cdt to start:

First open you shell and type `sudo -s` and start eclipse as root. After this you should be able to run it as normal user.

But this has to be done for the first as root.

Comment: Simpler one-line solution that doesn't need a root shell: `sudo eclipse`